# Outline not working properly on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am trying to put some custom outline in order to reach some web accessibility suggestions. But I can't make with Firefox.

This is how it looks on Chrome:

[image]

And that icon is actually an anchor.

On Firefox, it is only outlining the whole document, like this:

[image]

On Firefox it is outlining the document and in the next tab it focuses on the search bar again.

Here you may see a Codepen I did: https://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/owRWag

Or a **code Snippet**:

```js
// This function sets outline on tab and removes it on click
var elArr = Array.from ? Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a")) : Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a")); // Fallback for IE because as usual nothing works there!

elArr.forEach(function(a) {
  return a.addEventListener("click", function() {
    $(a).addClass("no-outline").removeClass('custom-outline');
  });
});

elArr.forEach(function(a) {
  return a.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    $(a).removeClass("no-outline").addClass('custom-outline');
  });
});
// END
```

**CSS**

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.no-outline {
  outline: 0 !important;
}

.custom-outline:focus {
  outline: 2px dotted blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">one</a>
  <a href="#">two</a>
  <a href="#">three</a>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Firefox includes the document as a tab index in normal tabbing order: at some point when tabbing around the window, the document gets focus and is outlined. This appears to be different to the way Chrome behaves. Is there a problem after taking browser differences into account?

Comment: Your codepen isn't working on mobile : there is no outline at all.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer yes, that is a regular behavior. It shouldn't be an outline on mobile.

Comment: @Traktor53 the problem is not the focusing on the document by tabbing. The problem is that once it focus on the document, it is not accessing the rest of the anchors in the document on tab, it is just getting back to the search bar of the browser. So, is there a solution?

Comment: Unable to reproduce under Windows 7,  Firefox 54.0.1 desktop. After placing the posted code into an HTML document and clicking in the search bar, tabbing highlights the document and then outlines each link in turn.

Comment: Can't repliate on windows10, Firefox 54 desktop. It is navigating all the links on the page. Added code on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/x9jcx07h/show/

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a mac? OS X has a system-wide preference which Firefox honors (Chrome does not) that changes the behavior of the tab key in windows and dialogs. It is probably set to tab only to text boxes -- skipping anchor tags.

Search System Preferences for "full keyboard access" and you'll find it, or refer to the screenshot below:

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts Preferences].

Set to "All Controls" to make Firefox behave like Chrome on OSX.